# C# merging two object lists

Tags: c#, linq, object

I have two list that i want to merge into one list.
A list of computers in Active Directory and a list of computers in SCCM.

ListA contains:

```
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public string OperatingSystem { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogon { get; set; }
```

ListB contains:

```
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] AgentTime { get; set; }
    public string LastLogonUserName { get; set; }
```

I want to merge by ComputerName, but if i do it with join using (example):

```
    var query = from ObjectA in ListA
          join ObjectB in ListB on ObjectA.ComputerName equals ObjectB.ComputerName
          select new { computername = ObjectA.ComputerName, lastlogonusername = ObjectB.LastLogonUserName };
```

it only shows result that are both lists. I wanna make a list of computers in AD with the additional information for those that are also in SCCM

ListC containing:

```
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public string OperatingSystem { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogon { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] AgentTime { get; set; }
    public string LastLogonUserName { get; set; }
```

What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: the output you're getting is the result of your inner join.

Comment: See left outer join on following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: You are creating a dynamic object by `new {}`. Create a custom class, if you need.

Comment: As @AmitKumarGhosh said, this is an inner join. Do a left join and you get the infromation you want. There are plenty of left join LINQ examples

Comment: Can you give an example to an output you want? I did not understand it. By the comments I can understand that you want a left join? Is this so? It means you will get all the items in A and if it also have a pair in B it will be paired. Otherwise it will pair to a null/a default value.

Comment: Thanks all. Ofcouse outer join is the way. Sometimes you just got stuck in same thinking :) So adding into <variable> and from ObjectB in <variable>.DefaultIfEmpty working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an outer join:

```
var query =
      from ObjectA in ListA
      join ObjectB in ListB on ObjectA.ComputerName equals ObjectB.ComputerName into tmp
      from ObjectB in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
      select new { computername = ObjectA.ComputerName, lastlogonusername = ObjectB?.LastLogonUserName };
```

Note the use of `?.` on `ObjectB`: this is because if there is no matching item in `ListB`, `ObjectB` will be null.

(if you're not using C#6, you can do `ObjectB != null ? ObjectB.LastLogonUserName : null` instead)

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the quick answer. From the obove comments, i figured it out with the left outer join. But thanks pointing me in with the ?. not matching procedure instead of ObjectB == null ? "" : ObjectB.LastLogonUserName. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not instead add everything to one list then simply get a distinct list by ComputerName?

```
// Convert all B objects to A objects
var objectBsAsAs = ListB.Select(x => new ObjectA() { ComputerName = x.ComputerName, LastLogonUserName = x.LastLogonUserName });
// Add all B objects to the list of A objects
var allComputers = ListA.AddRange(objectBsAsAs);
// Get a distinct list based on ComputerName
var distinct = ListA.Distint(new ComputerNameComparer());

private class ComputerNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<ObjectA> 
{
    public bool Equals(ObjectA a, ObjectA b) 
    {
        return a.ComputerName == b.ComputerName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can thank by giving the answer a vote! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help -

```
        var l1 = new List<A>
        {
            new A
            {
                ComputerName = Dns.GetHostName(),
                LastLogon = DateTime.Now,
                OperatingSystem = "Windows"
            }
        };

        var l2 = new List<B>
        {
            new B
            {
                AgentTime = new DateTime[]{DateTime.Now},
                ComputerName = Dns.GetHostName(),
                LastLogonUserName = "me"
             }
        };


        var o = from r in l2
                join q in l1 on r.ComputerName equals q.ComputerName
                into grp
                from p in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new C
                {
                    AgentTime = r.AgentTime,
                    ComputerName = p.ComputerName,
                    LastLogon = p.LastLogon,
                    OperatingSystem = p.OperatingSystem,
                    LastLogonUserName = r.LastLogonUserName
                };
```